NSFetchedResultsController doesn't re-order UITableViewCell
I have 2 NSManagedObject as below.
@interface Discussion : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) TMMessage *lastMessage;
@end

@interface TMMessage : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * timeStamp;
@end

And NSSortDescriptor is set like:
let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Discussion.lastMessage.timeStamp), ascending: false))
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]

After performFetch() is called, everything works fine. It shows all the objects I have, and it update the lastMessage when there is a new message. The only issue is that when the lastMessage is set, the cell order is not updated.
The below delegate method is called with type == .update, not type == .move.
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<any NSFetchRequestResult>,
                didChange anObject: Any,
                at indexPath: IndexPath?,
                for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType,
                newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
switch type {
        case .insert:
            guard let newIndexPath else { return }
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            guard let indexPath else { return }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        case .move:
            guard let indexPath, let newIndexPath else { return }
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: newIndexPath)
        case .update:
            guard let indexPath else { return }
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
}

When a lastMessage is updated, I have to manually call performFetch() again, so the NSFetchedResultsController returns the right order. Is there a way to use the delegate method to update the cell order?
